# How do I fix the Cloud Bigtable Hello World example?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to run the [Cloud Bigtable Hello World](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/java/hello-world) example that illustrates connectivity to Google Bigtable.

The project builds fine when I execute

```
mvn package
```

I tried to run the example with the following command...

```
mvn exec:java -Dbigtable.projectID=GCLOUDPROJECT -Dbigtable.instanceID=BIGTABLEINSTANCE
```

where I substituted my values for GCLOUDPROJECT and BIGTABLEINSTANCE.

The maven build produces the following output...

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building cloud-bigtable-hello-world 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (default-cli) @ cloud-bigtable-hello-world ---
[WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:294)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find an appropriate constructor for com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_x.BigtableConnection
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableConfiguration.connect(BigtableConfiguration.java:183)
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableConfiguration.connect(BigtableConfiguration.java:156)
        at com.example.cloud.bigtable.helloworld.HelloWorld.doHelloWorld(HelloWorld.java:61)
        at com.example.cloud.bigtable.helloworld.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:149)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableConfiguration.connect(BigtableConfiguration.java:180)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/grpc/Status$Code
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.config.RetryOptions.<clinit>(RetryOptions.java:52)
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.config.RetryOptions$Builder.<init>(RetryOptions.java:90)
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.config.BigtableOptions$Builder.<init>(BigtableOptions.java:95)
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableOptionsFactory.fromConfiguration(BigtableOptionsFactory.java:290)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractBigtableConnection.<init>(AbstractBigtableConnection.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractBigtableConnection.<init>(AbstractBigtableConnection.java:111)
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_x.BigtableConnection.<init>(BigtableConnection.java:49)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.grpc.Status$Code
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 21 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.142 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-13T13:48:18-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (default-cli) on project cloud-bigtable-hello-world: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: Could not find an appropriate constructor for com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_x.BigtableConnection: io/grpc/Status$Code: io.grpc.Status$Code -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

It looks like there is a dependency missing.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: do `mvn package exec:java -Dbigtable.projectID=GCLOUDPROJECT -Dbigtable.instanceID=BIGTABLEINSTANCE` ?

Comment: This is the problem:  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.grpc.Status$Code`.  Something Bad is happening in your classpath relating to io.grpc related classes.  Would you be able to delete your cached io/grpc maven files?